# Adding visit function to AST visitor prevents other methods from firing

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, python-ast

Using the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), I run into a weird issue:

#### Code

```py
import ast
from _ast import Try

code = """
def my_add(a, b):
    try:
        return a + b
    except TypeError:
        return a + b
"""

class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Try(self, node: Try):
        print(node)
        return node


Visitor().visit(ast.parse(code))
```

#### Output

```
<ast.Try object at 0xXXX>
```

Here, `Visitor().visit()` (a [ast.NodeVisitor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=functiondef#ast.NodeVisitor) subclass) prints `<ast.Try object at 0xXXX>`, but if I add a `visit_FunctionDef` method to the `Visitor` class:

#### Code with visit_FunctionDef

```py
import ast
from _ast import Try

code = """
def my_add(a, b):
    try:
        return a + b
    except TypeError:
        return a + b
"""

class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Try(self, node: Try):
        print(node)
        return node

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node: ast.FunctionDef):
        print(node.name)
        return node

Visitor().visit(ast.parse(code))
```

#### Output

```
my_add
```

#### Expected Output

```
my_add
<ast.Try object at 0xXXX>
```

Now the only printed line is `my_add`, where I'd expect two lines, `my_add`, then `<ast.Try object at 0xXXX>`.

I checked and the `visit_Try` method seems okay, as it seems to respect what I can read here: [class ast.NodeVisitor.visit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=functiondef#ast.NodeVisitor.visit). It isn't deprecated either.

I don't understand this behaviour. How can I get the desired output?

Same behaviour in Python 3.9 and 3.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a call to [`.generic_visit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit) so that the children of the function node are visited. The children of a node aren't visited by default.

So, your `visit_FunctionDef` should look like:

```
def visit_FunctionDef(self, node: ast.FunctionDef):
    print(node.name)
    self.generic_visit(node)
    return node
```

This outputs:

```py
my_add
<_ast.Try object at 0x7fbce58dd250>
```

Comment: "Note that child nodes of nodes that have a custom visitor method won’t be visited unless the visitor calls generic_visit() or visits them itself." I didn't read the `generic_visit` documentation as I "guess" I didn't need it. Next time, I will try to open my eyes :D

Comment: Don't be so harsh on yourself, happens to all of us. :) Have a good one!